# Mongoose make partial transaction within a map of arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way I can update the value of one object in an array, without knowing the previous value of the second element?

```js
user.set(`history.${day}`, [{ morning: price }]);
```

I only want to update the morning price without specifically knowing what the value of afternoon is.

Picture of the document before the line above ran:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQVmY.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrCd0.png)

As you can see looking at the after picture, the second object in the 3rd array was deleted after updating the price from 50 to 100, is there anyway to do partial transactions?

Model schema:

```
const subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  morning: Number, afternoon: Number
},{_id: false});

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: String,
    price: Number,
    history: { type: Map, of: [subSchema] }
  }
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need history to be a `Map` of arrays for your use case? For this example it looks like you have individual days as the `subSchema` which could as well be one object with `morning` and `afternoon` instead of an array containing objects that have only one of the two.

Comment: @als Defining the schemas such as this is what you're talking about? https://pastebin.com/yNT1iJQZ

Comment: I was thinking about changing `history: { type: Map, of: [subSchema] }` to `history: { type: Map, of: subSchema }` for starters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your schema as is you need to provide set with the complete path to the value that you want to change:

```js
user.set(`history.${day}.${index}.morning`,  price);
```

which requires some way to find the index you want to modify.